# Get winlows login name after launching python as another user

Tags: python, python-2.7, py2exe

I have created an exe of my python file using py2exe and running this exe with a particular user(for directory access permission).Now that the executable is in a different login, How can i get the username of the system.

```
getpass.getuser()
os.getenv('username')
```

return the current user the exe is running .
How can i get the actual login of the user?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If i understand correctly.

Logged in as a user(Geoff). Geoff runs executable as Administrator user, and you would like to grab Geoff's username? If this is what you are asking, here is my solution.

```
def getregvalue(key, subkey, value):

    import _winreg

    key = getattr(_winreg, key)
    handle = _winreg.OpenKey(key, subkey)
    (value, type) = _winreg.QueryValueEx(handle, value)

return value

print getregvalue("HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE", "SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows NT\\CurrentVersion\\Winlogon", "DefaultUserName")
```

This will fetch the logged in username from the registry as opposed to from the privilege token from the user running the process.

Comment: Exactly what i was looking for,!, i saw similar examples which mostly referred to using subprocesswin32... but this solution is a clean way to acheive that. Thank you!,